# How to build, drill-down SharePoint reports? (How to show detail reports, after clicking respective Bar-column of an Bar-chart report.?)

Tags: reports, bi

## **Requirement:**

let us suppose,
we need three levels of SharePoint BI report in our dashboard.

### 1. Yearly Status reports of All Projects.

### 2. Department wise status of All Project.

### 3. Project Progress report.

let suppose user clicks on first bar-column of Yearly status report, then next Detail report of that particular department should be drill-down.

after that suppose user clicks on any Bar-column Project-Name from departments, the Progressive report of that Project should be appear.

Kindly suggest any out-of-box BI features, or any costume development etc.
Any suggestion, Discussion or guidelines will be heartily appreciated.

Thanking You,

Shaikh Naseer.

---